# EXC_BREAKPOINT on dismissing an UIImagePickerViewController while in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

I am working on a chat app with picture messaging (supports Portrait and Landscape orientations), recently updated to Swift 2.3.
I am running into this problem where dismissing the UIImagePickerController results in the app crashing with a EXC_BREAKPOINT (in both cases "Use Photo" and "Cancel"), and cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing it. Removing the `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` line removes the crash (though leaves the picker on the screen), so I believe that the root of the problems lies there.

Here is how I set up and call the UIImagePicker:

```
let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a Photo", style: .Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController();
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
```

And here are the methods that handle the event that an image was picked.

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        if image != nil {
            print("Got image");
            uploadToS3(image!);
        }
          self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `picker.dismiss...` instead of `self.dismiss...`.

Comment: Hey rmaddy! Thanks for the response - but unfortunately, no luck. As additional detail, this error seems to be happening primarily if I switch from Portrait orientation to Landscape in the Picker.